# Setting datagridview 'FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex' in CellMouseEnter event

Tags: c#, winforms

I am setting 'FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex' to required row index to adjust the dataGridView scroll bar position.

I am facing problem if i set that value with in dataGridView's "CellMouseEnter" event as follows

```
private void MyDataGridView_CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyDataGridView.Rows.Count > 11 && e.RowIndex > 10)
    {
       MyDataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex++;
    }
}
```

My problem is that when mouse enters the row whose index >11, the scrollbar position (Vertical scrollbar) is going to end instead of its 'FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex' incremented by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Since 'MyDataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex++' is changing row position, Mouse pointer enters new row and this again executes "CellMouseEnter" event that gets repeated till last row.